# Can not edit the form from sails.js

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

Hey guys I'm really new at sails.js and I'm using version 1.0 of it. I just tried to create a CRUD application on adding article to my list and showing them. All goes right but when I want to delete or edit it says 404 error. I am going through this tutorial series and as I know this series is using sails js version 0.12. 
I am using mongodb as my database as a default. Data insertion is going well but problem is when I wanted to edit or delete it. Here I think the problem is getting the id value from the url. I skipped the edit portion here and posted the delete portion here.

**api/controllers/ ArticleController.js**

```
    module.exports = {
         delete:  function(req, res){
            Articles.destroy({id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.send(500,'Database Error');
                }

                res.redirect('/articles/list');
            });
            return false;
        }
    };
```

**api/models/ Articles.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title:{
      type:'string'
    },
    body:{
      type:'string'
    }
  },

};
```

**views/pages list.ejs**

```
<h1 class="display-4">Articles</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% articles.forEach(function(article){ %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= article.id %></td>
                <td><%= article.title %></td>
                <td>
                    <form class="d-inline" action="/articles/delete/<%= article.id %>" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**config/route.js**

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'pages/homepage'
  },    
};
```

Comment: 404 usually occurs when the router is not matching. Can you show me your route file?

Comment: I did not know how to add routes.

Comment: You can go to config/route.js and add a route there like 'POST articles/delete/:id' : 'ArticleController.delete'

Comment: What if I give automatic routes? Will it do the same or not ?

Comment: @SarojSasmal Thanks mate